# How can I add a grey hover effect on the image when there inside HTML img src="image.jpeg"

Tags: hover

I'm trying to add a slight grey colour to the image when you hover over it, I'm implemented a jquery slider and it pulls in the images via the code below

```
<li>
<img src="new_z1.jpg" alt="" width="250" height="100">  </li>
```

Whats the best way to add a grey hover effect to the images?

Here is the site, the carousel is at the bottom of the page with all the logo's

http://goo.gl/CoZgB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to make your images grey scale? If it's that so, just use this

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/35zJ3/)

Reverse way  [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/35zJ3/1/)

```
img:hover {
     filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); /* Firefox 10+, Firefox on Android */
     filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Chrome 19+, Safari 6+, Safari 6+ iOS */
}
```

If you need smoothness, just use CSS3 transitions :)

Comment: I'm trying to get it so that they start off as grey and turn to the normal colour?

Comment: Just hover out and it will turn to normal color

Comment: I mean so it is grey at the start before we hover, then when we hover it turns to the normal colour

Comment: @user2265685 Use 2 images, on hover change the source

Comment: can we not set them to grey without changing the actually image, and just make it change to the normal colour after you hover.

Comment: @user2265685 Oops I am sorry, I misunderstood your comment, wait, am posting a demo

Comment: thankyou :) would i add the css transition to the hover state?

Comment: I've done it thankyou, didn't know this was possible with a webkit

Comment: With transitions http://jsfiddle.net/35zJ3/2/ , just not sure for the svg but added cross browser transitions :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a demo that helped with the same thing:

http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/html5-grayscale-image-hover

Alternatively you can cause a different image to load when you hover. This requires much less code, but would require another image load.

Comment: yeah this is the effect that I'm trying to get.